# Text file gets emptied and loses all of its data when the power cuts in Java

Tags: java, java-io

i have an application which accesses a chosen file and reads the data(text in my case) inside it and does some calculations then updates the text and rewrites it into the file.

the application works perfectly fine in terms of accessing files and rewriting them except in one case

here is the case: if the user uses a Desktop and if the user triggers an event that leads to file operations(reading and writing) and in the same time power got cut then after launching the desktop again the file still exists but it has no data in it(it is entirely emptied)

keep this mind that this is only happening when using a Desktop(it doesn't occur on laptops) and only exactly if a file operation has been triggered a split second before the power outage.

i was wondering is there any workaround in java to prevent happening such a thing, i know chances of this happening is very low but it happened and that is why i am here.

Comment: sure. save the file. Or copy data from that file and write to a new and have the old file deleted once you successfully write the new file

Comment: "i was wondering is there any workaround in java to prevent happening such a thing" - do you want Java to prevent power getting cut? Don't think that is possible.

Comment: i'm saving it but as i stated it's happening when the power on the desktop goes off and prevents the operation to finish and also deletes the whole data inside it

Comment: @moamennnn66 as I said, if you just *read* the file and write to a new file, the worst that happens is your new file is blank. Once you attempt to overwrite a file there is always going to be a chance all your data is lost. Unless you are using pen and paper.

Comment: @Amongalen nah i was expecting java to preserve the data after power outage, i wish there was something to be done about people trying to be funny when it is not needed.

Comment: @sleepToken thanks i kinda dig what are you trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the power goes off while you are writing a file, there are no guarantees<sup>1</sup> that the file will be written completely.

You can use `FileDescriptor.sync()` to reduce the window of vulnerability (by forcing the OS to flush writes to physical disk), but you can't eliminate it completely.

But as @creinig says, the normal way to do this is to write the data into a temporary file and then rename the temporary file.  Many OSes can perform a file rename operation atomically.

---

Incidentally, you say this:

> This is only happening when using a desktop computer (it doesn't occur on laptops) ...

A laptop typically has a battery and is not vulnerable to physical power cuts.  When you press the power-off button on a laptop, the OS probably gets a chance to flush the file system before the laptop powers down.

<sup>1 - Certainly not with a conventional file system.  A transactional file system (e.g. [Transactional NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS)) may offer some guarantees, but I'm not sure if the Java runtime understands this.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The classical solution to this would be to write the changed contents to a temp file and afterwards rename the temp file to the correct name. That way an interruption (a) leaves the temp file empty and the original file untouched or (b) causes the temp file to not be renamed, leaving the original file untouched.

Comment: seems true, but one thing, renaming the file to a name that already exists in the same directory will result in overriding that file?